# Using Injector Class in place of ReflectiveInjector class

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-scope

I am trying to dynamic load data in angular. In my approach i had used below code to load data -

```
 const inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map(inputName => {
  return { provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName] };
});
const resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(
  resolvedInputs,
  this.cardComponent.parentInjector
);

const componentType = this.content.resolve(data.component);
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);

const component = factory.create(injector);

this.cardComponent.insert(component.hostView);
```

Lint has pointed that ReflectiveInjector will be depreciated. How should i use Injector so that my current code should work properly.
I tried approach mentioned in below pages but it didn't tell about the resolve() and fromResolvedProviders() methods.

[Link 1](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-introduces-staticinjector-should-you-care-4e059eca030c) [Link 2](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-how-staticinjector-replaces-reflectiveinjector-6f303d2798f6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer of it. Below is the code that I have used -

```
 const inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map(inputName => {
  return { provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName] };
});

const injector = Injector.create(
 { providers: inputProviders,
  parent : this.cardComponent.parentInjector
});

const componentType = this.content.resolve(data.component);
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);

const component = factory.create(injector);

this.cardComponent.insert(component.hostView);
```

One can read more here [1](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#create) [2](https://medium.com/@nima_ap/creating-a-responsive-dashboard-in-angular-5-from-scratch-147f6a493d9e)